# Why am I getting this body error?

Tags: scheme, racket

Every time I run this code, I get the error message: "define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part." I have tried again and again to fix this, but I haven't found the solutions. Does anyone have any idea of how I can fix it? Sorry for the long code, I figured I should include it all or it wouldn't make sense. Thanks!

```
(define MT (empty-scene 50 50))

; A Polygon is one of: 
; – (list Posn Posn Posn)
; – (cons Posn Polygon)

; A NELoP is one of: 
; – (cons Posn empty)
; – (cons Posn NELoP)

; Polygon -> Image 
; adds an image of p to MT
(define (render-polygon p)
  (local 
    [;Polygon -> Posn
     ; extracts the last item from p
     (define (last p) 
       (cond
         [(empty? (rest (rest (rest p)))) (third p)]
         [else (last (rest p))]))]
    [;Image Posn Posn -> Image
     (define (render-line im p q)
       (add-line
        im (posn-x p) (posn-y p) (posn-x q) (posn-y q) "red"))]
    [;NELop -> Image
     ;connects the posns in p in an image
     (define (connect-dots p)
       (cond
         [(empty? (rest p)) MT]
         [else
          (render-line
           (connect-dots (rest p)) (first p) (second p))]))])
  (render-line (connect-dots p) (first p) (last p)))
```

New code (still not working):

```
; Polygon -> Image 
; adds an image of p to MT
(define (render-polygon p)
  (local 
    [;Polygon -> Posn
     ; extracts the last item from p
     (define (last p) 
       (cond
         [(empty? (rest (rest (rest p)))) (third p)]
         [else (last (rest p))]))
    ;Image Posn Posn -> Image
     (define (render-line im p q)
       (add-line
        im (posn-x p) (posn-y p) (posn-x q) (posn-y q) "red"))
    ;NELop -> Image
     ;connects the posns in p in an image
     (define (connect-dots p)
       (cond
         [(empty? (rest p)) MT]
         [else
          (render-line
           (connect-dots (rest p)) (first p) (second p))]))
  (render-line (connect-dots p) (first p) (last p))]))
```

Comment: Also, your code isn't too long at all (I have seen some horrendous questions with over 100 lines). Thank you for posting code with enough detail for me to work on. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `render-line` expression has to be *inside* the `local` form, not after it. Also, all your `define`s should be inside *one* subform in the `local`, not each in its own subform. So, it should look like:

```
(local [(define (last p)
          ...)
        (define (render-line im p q)
          ...)
        (define (connect-dots p)
          ...)]
  (render-line ...))
```

Comment: I made these changes (thank you, so many errors I missed out on!), but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: sure, just added it to the original question!

Comment: oh no, I just realized I hadn't properly fixed the subforms of local. I did that now and it works, thank you so much!